# What happens to the baby world turtles?

Tags: discworld

In the end of *The Light Fantastic* the Great A'Tuin finally reaches the red star, and baby turtles hatch, each complete with four baby elephants and a tiny discworld.

I'm seriously doubting there is any news on this, but do we ever find out anything about these new worlds? I've not read the final couple of novels, nor the young adult ones, though of course there may be information in any of the novels and I've missed / forgotten. Or perhaps is there any indication of anything *planned* to be revealed had the series not sadly ended?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I'm sad to say that they wander off into the void and are never heard from again. The 8 miniature 'Chelys Galactica' don't make an appearance in any later Pratchett books, stories or writings.

They're briefly referred to in *[The Ultimate Discworld Companion](https://discworld.com/products/books/the-ultimate-discworld-companion/)*, but we don't learn anything new.

> After the events of The Light Fantastic, the Great A’Tuin was orbited
> by eight baby turtles, each with four small world elephant calves and
> tiny discworlds, covered in smoke and volcanoes. **They have
> subsequently begun their own cosmic journeys.**

Comment: Did Pratchett write "and are never heard of again" or do we just not hear of them again?

Comment: @MacCooper - The latter. I've read all the Pratchett novels as well as the short stories and there's simply no mention of them.

Comment: awesome, just wanted to check Pratchett hadn't written them away. Ugh that's dissapointing.

Comment: Pratchett is on one of them

Comment: I expect a giant picture of a tiny star turtle going into the darkness. And at least three quotes!